# Powershell Command to Copy Files by Date Modified to a new location and maintain folder structure from old location

Tags: powershell

Im trying to copy all files from a network drive with a certain modify date and maintain the folder structure in the new location.  can you guys help?

thanks

Comment: [You don't need PowerShell for that](http://superuser.com/questions/562375/how-to-copy-only-new-files-and-only-those-that-are-modified-after-a-certain-date).

Comment: what can i use then?  I see robocopy but that doesnt let me specify a date only a min and a max

Comment: You can specify both at once: `robocopy /S /MINAGE:YYYYMMDD /MAXAGE:YYYYMMDD <source> <dest>`. Maxage should be set to the day you want. Minage should be set to the next day.

Comment: If you need finer granularity then indeed PS is your friend. [Some examples](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/cf81ddf2-7b74-4599-9e04-572469dfc65d/copying-files-based-on-last-write-time-help-a-powershell-newbie?forum=ITCG).

Answer (score 1):

I'm feeling generous, so I can just feed you a script despite your lack of "I've tried `<some code>` but it's giving me these errors" in your question. For the future you may want to read [Jon Skeet's 'Writing the perfect question'](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and remember that this site is here to help people through problems, not to just do your work for you.

Ok, getting off my soap box, this will search a share, compare the LastModified date against a date you provide, and then copy it to your destination, creating folders as needed

```
$Source = "\\Server01\Share`$\Target\Folder"
$Dest = "D:\Network Backup"
$TrgtDate = "06/04/2014"
gci $source -File -Recurse|%{
    $target=$_.fullname -replace "($([regex]::escape($Source)))(.*?)($([regex]::escape($_.Name)))","$Dest`$2"
    If(!(Test-Path $Target)){New-Item -Path $Target -ItemType Directory|Out-Null}
    Copy-Item $_ -Destination $target
}
```

Comment: I like this one as well - http://whathaveyoutried.com/  :-)